# Transfer array values to image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the values of the links on each list item and cycle them into my .skater_large image src.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="skater_multiview">
      <li><a href="skater1_big.jpg"><img src="skater1-thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="skater2_big.jpg"><img src="skater2-thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="skater3_big.jpg"><img src="skater3-thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="skater_large" src="empty.jpg" />
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and the js:

```
        $('#skater_multiview li a').each(function(click) {

        var cardboard = new Array();
        for(i=0; i<$('#skater_multiview li a').length; i++) {

            // gathering all skater carousel list link values
            var pro_link = $('#skater_multiview li a').eq(i).attr('href');

            // adding hrefs to array
            cardboard.push(pro_link);
            // pushing cardboard array values into img src
            $('.skater_large').attr('src',cardboard[i]);
            };
        });
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.  Could you state the problem you are having?  What are you expecting to see and what does not match that expectation?

Comment: More info would help. It seems like the for-loop will execute so fast that the src of `$('.skater_large')` will instantaneously go to the last one. I'm thinking a timer would work better, but as I say, I don't get your intent.

Comment: Your code is also confusing.  No `#skater_multiview li a` has an href attribute, so why are you trying to access it?

Comment: I'm able to alert(carboard); to find the src's, but i'd like to put them into the .skater_large src, cycling through each value in my array each click.

Comment: @fakerainbrigand are you sure? It looks just that way to me.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand each list items link has an href attribute...they just happen to be images

Comment: @seanmk basically for each click i want the .skater_large img src to become the next indexOf(cardboard); Am I making sense?

Comment: @SkipZepeda, ah, sorry.  I get confused when three elements are on one line (nothing wrong with it, my brain just doesn't process it well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for just a click event that replaces the `src` .. This should do

```
var cardboard = [];
 $('#skater_multiview li a').each(function (index) {
     // gathering all skater carousel list link values
     var pro_link = $(this).attr('href');
     // adding hrefs to array
     cardboard.push(pro_link);
     // pushing cardboard array values into img src
     $('.skater_large').attr('src', cardboard[i]);
 });

// Attach a click event for slater when clicked
// gets the next image
var curr;
$('.skater_large').click(function () {
     // Get the href attribute
    var index;
    if(curr)
        index = curr >= cardboard.length ? 0 ? curr;
     else
         curr = 0;
     $('.skater_large').attr('src', cardboard[curr]);
        curr++;
 });
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. I'm making a note of the setTimeout you used as well. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)